# How to write a while statement in c?

Tags: c, while-loop

I should write a C `while` statement that continues while `x` is both larger than 10 and a multiple of either 6 or 7.  I only need to include the actual `while` statement, not the entire loop!

I know it may look funny to you, but this is what I have so far.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    int x;

    while (x > 10, x % 7 = 0 || x % 6 = 0) {
        printf("%d\n", x);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where did you read about syntax like this?

Comment: You are not doing anything to x.. you have `,` where did you get this?

Comment: @Ava, I assume at some point you actually assign a value to *x* and your code will also change the value of *x* inside the loop. If both of those conditions are not met, the loop with either never execute or it will become an infinite loop.

Comment: If someone told you, he should have given you enough information already to do this your own. This is actually homework. Otherwise ask her so he can improve her teaching style..

Comment: You should have studied about logical && and || operator before posting this question as it is  basic question

Answer (score 3):

Logical and is `&&`. As an operator, `,` is "ignore the result of the thing to the left".

Comment: Forgive my confusion - I though `,` was the sequencing operator, requiring that the operand to the left be evaluated before the operand to the right.  ???

Comment: @BobJarvis So? It's not like `x > 10` has any side effects you could observe.

Answer (score 3):

Your Boolean logic and comparison both use the wrong syntax. It should be like this:

```
while (x > 10 && (x % 7 == 0 || x % 6 == 0)) {
```

The comma (`,`) is not a valid Boolean operator. What you wanted is `&&` (logical AND). You need parentheses around the other two expressions because AND (`&&`) has higher precedence than OR (`||`).

And `=` is for setting values; `==` is for comparing them.

Finally, as others pointed out, you don't set `x` anywhere in the code that you have posted. So, your loop will not run. And you don't modify `x` in the loop, so, if you ever get into the loop, you will never get out.

Answer (score 2):

Your while statement should read

```
while (x > 10 && (x % 7 == 0 || x % 6 == 0))
```

Note the use of `&&` for "boolean and", and `==` for "equality comparison".

Answer (score 2):

The program can look like

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    int x;

    printf( "Enter an integer number: " );
    scanf( "%d", &x );

    while ( x > 10 && ( x % 7 == 0 || x % 6 == 0 ) ) 
    {
        printf( "%d\n", x );
        printf( "Enter next integer number: " );
        scanf( "%d", &x );
    }
}
```

Or you could enlarge the condition in the while loop the following way (to check that the input is correct)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    int x;

    printf( "Enter an integer number: " );

    while ( scanf( "%d", &x ) == 1 && x > 10 && ( x % 7 == 0 || x % 6 == 0 ) ) 
    {
        printf( "%d\n", x );
        printf( "Enter next integer number: " );
    }
}
```

As for your condition in the while loop then it has two errors

```
while (x > 10, x % 7 = 0 || x % 6 = 0)
```

It uses the comma operator instead of logical operator && and it uses the assignment operator as for example `x % 7 = 0` instead of the comparison operator `x % 7 == 0`. Also variable `x` was not initialized.

Answer (score 1):

> I should Write a C while statement that continues while x is both
>   larger than 10 and a multiple of either 6 or 7. I Only need to include
>   the actual while statement, not the entire loop!

Let's analyze the condition that will go in the while() statement:

> x is both larger than 10 and a multiple of either 6 or 7

Can be expressed as

> x is greater than 10 AND a multiple of 6 OR multiple of 7

So let's code that in C:

> x is greater than 10

```
x>10
```

> AND

```
&&
```

> x multiple of 6 OR x multiple of 7

```
(x%6)==0 || (x%7)==0
```

Then, all together

```
x>10 && ( (x%6)==0 || (x%7)==0 )
```

So your while sentence is like this:

```
while (x>10 && ( (x%6)==0 || (x%7)==0 ))
{
  stuff...
}
```

Comment: What does this "a supporter of retrocomputing" mean?

Comment: In my profile? It means that I am very fond of old computers, like the personal microcomputers that start spreading in late 70's and all the 80's. In Russia, this would mean all the Pentagon and Scorpion clones of the ZX Spectrum.

Comment: But what does supporter mean? What kind of activity does it imply?

Comment: A supporter (in this context) is someone that just likes these kind of computers, enjoys tinkering with them. In my case, I also fix them and even design modern versions of them by using FPGA. To learn more, please visit http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retrocomputing

Answer (score 0):

Here can be the Solution Ava

```
    while (x > 10 && (x % 7 == 0 || x % 6 == 0)) {
```